# Trying to create SUMIF statements inside and IF statement

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I currently have a `SUMIF` statement that outputs a graph, based upon the value of a dropdown.

```
=SUMIF('Rev Tracking'!$C$16:$C$57,$E$21,'Rev Tracking'!I$16:I$57)
```

This creates a sum of all the values in `I$16:I$57` where the value of `$E$21` is found in `$C$16:$C$57`.

I'm looking to select from multiple ranges of cells dependent upon the dropdown result, but I'm not sure you can nest `SUMIFS` inside an `IF` statement.. i.e.

```
=if(E21="Client1",(SUMIF('Rev Tracking'!$C$65:$C$76,$E$21,'Rev Tracking'!I$65:I$76)),(SUMIF('Rev Tracking'!$C$85:$C$100,$E$21,'Rev Tracking'!I$85:I$100)))
```

This doesn't work and feels like it should be quite different.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try nested `=QUERY()` inside an `IF` statement.

E.g.

`=IF($E$21 = "Client1", 
QUERY(<<CELL_RANGE_HERE>>, "SELECT SUM(Col1) WHERE col1 = '''&$E$21&''' ", 1), 
IF($E$21 = "Client2", 
QUERY(<<CELL_RANGE_HERE>>, "SELECT SUM(Col1) WHERE col1 = '''&$E$21&''' ", 1), ... ))`

I've found this to be helpful when trying to sum different ranges.